# Webform redirect

Tags: webforms

I'd like to do something pretty straightforward: After user fills out a [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform), I'd like a button that simply redirects them to a URL (in this case it's to a demo sandbox). Of course I'd want the user to fill in their info to capture for lead-generation purposes. My [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) is set up correctly in that it correctly captures all the user fields and submits them to me via email. However, upon completion "click" I'd like to have the user redirected to a determined internal URL www.mysite.com/foo

I can't figure out how this is done with the vanilla webform settings. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 8):

If i had to redirect the users after submission than i would go to the already created webfrom, click on

- **Webform**(on top of the form)->**Form settings**

[image]

After scrolling down a bit you will see **Redirection location**

Choose **Custom URL** and enter your Internal URL ***www.mysite.com/foo***

[image]

Thats it you are done.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need code for this.

Install this modules:

- [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules)
- [webform rules](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules)

Now add a rule that redirects the user to your URL after a webform submission.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your webform and go to Form Settings.
In Redirection location select Custom URL.
That's all.

I usually use the rule method that BetaRide suggested. If you are using any rule logic with your webform go with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try native idea [`drupal_redirect_form`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7)

> Redirects the user to a URL after a form has been processed.

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'node';
```

Or to redirect to 'node/123?foo=bar#baz':

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  'node/123',
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'foo' => 'bar',
    ),
    'fragment' => 'baz',
  ),
);
```

You can use it in [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if($form_id == 'YORWEBFORMID') {
   $form_state['redirect'] = 'node';
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly would I key this code into? Am I creating a module to do it?