# Add A Redirect Link In Webform Submit Button

Tags: webforms

I want to add a redirect link on Webform submission button when a user submit a webform I want to redirect them in different page.

How can I redirect a user after they submit the webform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is duplicated question.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/webform-redirect)

**But here is the answer**
If i had to redirect the users after submission than i would go to the already created webfrom, click on

- **Webform**(on top of the form)->**Form settings**

[image]

After scrolling down a bit you will see **Redirection location**

Choose **Custom URL** and enter your Internal URL ***www.mysite.com/foo***

[image]

Thats it you are done.

Comment: If this the answer that you was looking for. Please up vote this answer and click the check mark.

Comment: Done All things But I Cannot Vote My Reputation Is Not 15 I Have Done Tick